# call a servlet's post method from another application's servlet

Tags: java, servlet-3.0

I want  to call a servlet's POST method from another application, in which I am passing request and response. Can anyone tell me how is that possible?

Comment: How are you calling the servlet?

Answer (score 0):

If your servlet is invoked in an HTTP POST then you can do an [HTTP 307 redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6451542/16959) to another servlet and it will call it's doPost.  If you want to POST to a different page from a servlet (or any Java method) you can compose a POST with something like [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/methods/post.html) like this:

```
PostMethod post = new PostMethod("http://jakarata.apache.org/");
NameValuePair[] data = {
  new NameValuePair("user", "joe"),
  new NameValuePair("password", "bloggs")
};
post.setRequestBody(data);
// execute method and handle any error responses.
...
InputStream in = post.getResponseBodyAsStream();
```