# How to Copy HTTP request and Redirect It?

Tags: servlets, httprequest, httpresponse

I want to redirect a HTTP request to another URL with every current information. I mean I should preserve header information etc. I have that piece of code:

```
Enumeration headerNames = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getHeaderNames();
while (headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
    String headerName = (String) headerNames.nextElement();
    if (headerName.equals("UNAME")) {
        String username = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getHeader(headerName);
        ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendRedirect(((HttpServletRequest) request).getRequestURI() + "?uname=" + username);
    }
}
```

When I run it I get 401 error. Original request has cookies, HTTP header information etc. etc. I think that reason is I do not redirect such kind of information. I want to copy original and just want to redirect it to another URL.

Comment: Have you tried a 307? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449894/servlet-or-jsp-how-do-i-redirect-a-post-request-without-data-loss/

Answer (score -2):

Set the request header information and other request parameters before redirecting to a different url

request.setAttribute("PARAMETER1",parameter1);
response.sendRedirect("TO A DIFFERENT URL");